# RMI timeout from remote machime

Tags: java, timeout, rmi

I could connect to the RMI server with my client code in the same machine. But when I access it over the internet from another machine I get timeout exception after few minutes.

I checked the port and is listening.

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 11.11.11.11; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:110)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
at $Proxy0.echoString(Unknown Source)
at client.UseMon.main(UseMon.java:42)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
... 7 more
```

What should I check now.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there firewall in your network that could be preventing you from accessing certain ports? Can you ping your remote machine and check it is reachable from your computer? Can you telnet and check the port in question is opened?

Comment: no I could connect to the port thro telnet

Comment: If your machine or the server has a firewall active, that could be preventing you from reaching the server. Check your settings, do you have a firewall running on your machine or in the server? Is the port of your remote application closed?

Answer (score 0):

"...over the internet from another machine..." - is your server behind a router? You'll have to forward ports in this case. This would explain why it works locally but not remotely.